# Building a Hakyll site in “development” or “release” mode

Tags: haskell, hakyll

I am building a site with Hakyll and I only want my Google Analytics code to be included if I am deploying the site, not when I’m just testing it using “site server”. Ideally I’d be able to write something like

```
$if(deploying)$
    <script src=".../whatever.js"></script>
$endif$
```

in a template and have that content included when I run “site build” but not “site server”. Does Hakyll have any built-in way to determine which subcommand is being run? Or can I somehow access the process’s environment variables?

Comment: This is potentially a nice feature request. Meanwhile, it might be possible to write a hack of some sort using  [`getArgs`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-Environment.html#v:getArgs) from `System.Environment`.